# how does jQuery return the HTML node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that create a jQuery element and return an object which inside has the element itself and the reference fro some method

for example (I'm typing the code and maybe there are some typo)

```
var obj = {};
obj.fn = function(){console.log("Hello, World!")};
obj.create = function(){
var temp = $("<div/>", {id:"test"})
return {object:temp, fn:obj.fn}
}
```

for example I can create a variable and assign to it the obj.create like

```
var test = obj.create()
```

now on test is an object and with test.object I have the HTML node and with test.fn i can call obj.fn, so far so good, now here's my question:

How can I append the test.object to the body for example ($("body").append(test.object))
without specify the .object but just test and still be able to call test.fn()?

jQuery for example in here

```
$("<div/>", {id:"test"})
```

return the HTML node that can be appended anywhere but can still call some method like show() or remove().

Any thought?

**EDIT**

I did some research and I found out that what I want to accomplish can be done use and array.

Basically and array is an instance of the object Array, so you can add your own method to a new array, for example the jQuery object is an instance of the array object, the numeric index are the reference to the HTML node and there are all the jQuery method, for example:

```
>>> var obj = $("#banner-secondary")
undefined
>>> for (item in obj){console.log(item)}
0
length
context
selector
jquery
constructor
init
size
toArray
get
pushStack
each
ready
slice
first
last
eq
map
end
push
sort
splice
extend
data
removeData
queue
dequeue
delay
clearQueue
promise
attr
removeAttr
prop
removeProp
addClass
removeClass
toggleClass
hasClass
val
on
one
off
bind
unbind
delegate
undelegate
trigger
triggerHandler
find
has
not
filter
is
closest
index
add
addBack
andSelf
parent
parents
parentsUntil
next
prev
nextAll
prevAll
nextUntil
prevUntil
siblings
children
contents
text
wrapAll
wrapInner
wrap
unwrap
append
prepend
before
after
remove
empty
clone
html
replaceWith
detach
domManip
appendTo
prependTo
insertBefore
insertAfter
replaceAll
css
show
hide
toggle
serialize
serializeArray
blur
focus
focusin
focusout
load
resize
scroll
unload
click
dblclick
mousedown
mouseup
mousemove
mouseover
mouseout
mouseenter
mouseleave
change
select
submit
keydown
keypress
keyup
error
contextmenu
hover
ajaxStart
ajaxStop
ajaxComplete
ajaxError
ajaxSuccess
ajaxSend
fadeTo
animate
stop
finish
slideDown
slideUp
slideToggle
fadeIn
fadeOut
fadeToggle
offset
position
offsetParent
scrollLeft
scrollTop
innerHeight
height
outerHeight
innerWidth
width
outerWidth
colorbox
flexslider
tinyNav
```

0 is the reference to the HTML node of the id banner-secondary.

Thanks to Kevin B for his fiddle, i forked it and test the code, here's mine:
http://jsfiddle.net/wuE4z/

Comment: jQuery **doesn't** return the HTML node. It returns a jQuery object that contains a reference to the HTML node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery objects have a collection similar to an array that stores the elements, not so much different from what you did above. You have a create method, now all you need is an appendTo method (and make a small modification to the create method so that the element is stored on object).

http://jsfiddle.net/jvXy2/

```
var obj = {};
obj.fn = function () {
    console.log("Hello, World!")
};
obj.create = function () {
    this.el = document.createElement("div");
    this.el.id = "test";
};
obj.appendTo = function(target) {
    target.appendChild(this.el);
};
obj.create();
obj.appendTo(document.getElementById("demo"));
```

obviously that is heavily simplified, jquery does a lot more behind the scenes. jQuery takes it a step further and uses a constructor that returns an instance of the jquery object so that you can have more than one. It also stores the elements on the object similar to how it would be stored in an array (0 indexed keys) with a length property that gets updated to represent the number of elements stored.

Comment: Thanks for your example, there is just one thing left I do not understand, let's assume `var div = $("<div>")`
if I want to add it to the DOM I can use `$("body").append(div)` or `div.appendTo("body")` if I use the code in the fiddle con I add the div to the DOM like the first example something like `$("body").append(obj)` and not `$("body").append(obj.el)`?
Thanks

Comment: sorry my question was incomplete, now it's fine

Comment: No, because obj is not a jquery object and is not a dom node. you would have to instead use `$("body").append(obj.el)` or `$(obj.el).appendTo("body");`

Comment: I edited my question to share with everyone the result of your help, thanks again